# Proper to let trade carry liberation, even possible?

Tags: sila, dana

No question that it isn't proper to let trades for world carry Dhamma, share Dhamma via market places, but what does one think in regard of receiving? Would Dhamma made avaliable by commerce take one out of this wheel?

Could people, who are not willing in providing sphere out of faith fist, based on generosity, ever match even the base? Or will they simply stay bond where they wish to receive?

*Question powered by...* grave defilements...

[image]

Comment: Why not? quod gratis asseritur, gratis negatur.

Comment: npthing is gratis in the world and liberation as well, good householder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129575/discussion-between-letsbuddhism-and-user21819).

Comment: I downvoted this question because it was asked with a clear answer in mind and the way the user responds to others doesn't seem to promote healthy discussions.

Comment: My friend, did I miss you.

Comment: "I downvoted this question because it was asked with a clear answer in mind and the way the user responds to others doesn't seem to promote healthy discussions." that's how defilements act if touched. They wouldn't like to answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Would Dhamma made avaliable by commerce take one out of this wheel?

Making a bussiness out if Dhamma is a corruption in one who does it, it doesn't corrupt the Dhamma.

Therefore there is no apparent reason to assume that one who payed to learn the Dhamma would be deficient.

Comment: So householder thinks that Dhamma could be gained, liberation could be gained, by corrupt and not given ways? Did the payed gave him ways to go forth?

Comment: "thinks that Dhamma could be gained, liberation could be gained, by corrupt and not given ways?" No, that i do not think. "Did the payed gave him ways to go forth? I don't understand this.

Comment: Aren't there Jataka where people pay to learn the Dhamma? I am not sure but i think it's obvious that one who buys doesn't part-take in the offense of selling.

Comment: The wording you use "corrupt not given ways". Liberation can not be gained by corrupt ways but Buying a Dhamma talk or a Book is not a corruption in one who buys it.

Comment: One's evil kamma doesn't corrupt another, one is not heir to another's kamma.

Comment: 'I don't understand this.', seemingly, yet still thinking to be able to answer. Bond.

Comment: If buying Dhamma would block liberation then it would be close to anantarika-kamma. i don't think i can explain it due to the apparent language barrier

Comment: Well, wrong view, strong wrong view, is actually anantarika-kamma good householder, or is he able to cross the "language barrier"?

Comment: Please have mercy samana... If you care what i think then let's find an interpreter and i will explain, otherwise it's stressing me immensely

Comment: Let's try another door: If a gift (a gift!) isn't purified either on one or both sides, would it be of benefit beyond the world?

Comment: Based on Dakkhinavibhangasuttam; There is an offering that is neither purified by the giver nor by the receiver. Here, Samana, the giver is unvirtuous and bad-natured, and the receivers are unvirtuous and bad-natured. That unvirtuous person who, with a mind lacking in confidence, gives a gift that has been unrighteously obtained to unvirtuous person, who does not have great faith in actions and their results, that gift will not bring an extensive reward I say.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129613/discussion-between-letsbuddhism-and-user21819).

Answer (score 0):

Trading the Dhamma is wrong, according to [Ud 6.2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/ud/ud.6.02.than.html).

But selling a paperback book containing words of the Dhamma is not wrong, if the proceeds meant for the author, goes to charitable causes.

Ven. Ajahn Brahm has published books and has regular talks on YouTube. According to [this page](https://bswa.org/teachers/ajahn-brahm/ajahn-brahm-bio/):

> Ajahn Brahm has authored three popular books that are available
> commercially ... the royalties raised from sales of these books goes
> to the activities of the Buddhist Society of Western Australia.

Similarly, if videos of talks by Dhamma teachers are monetized on YouTube with ads, it's ok, if the money received by the YouTube channel owner, is then used for charitable causes.

It's only wrong if the money from such activities is used for financial profit and as a means of livelihood.

Of course, YouTube itself, and the book publishing company itself, may make profit, but this is only because they are providing a platform as a paid service. After all, they need money to maintain this platform and pay their employees.

What about the recipient of the Dhamma? Well, it's up to him to discover who is the right teacher and who is the wrong teacher. Sometimes, monks like Devadatta ([Iti 89](https://suttacentral.net/iti89/en/sujato)) or Sati ([MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/sujato)) are wrong teachers and a lay householder like Citta ([SN 41.5](https://suttacentral.net/sn41.5/en/sujato)) is the right teacher.

Comment: 'But selling a paperback book containing words of the Dhamma is not wrong, if the proceeds meant for the author, goes to charitable causes.', who says? Common traders sense?

Comment: 'Similarly, if videos of talks by Dhamma teachers are monetized on YouTube with ads, it's ok, if the money received by the YouTube channel owner, is then used for charitable causes.', so Dhamma can be use to feed the poor? Aside of youtube isn't a generous undertaking. Not to speak how a monk could use it...

Comment: 'What about the recipient of the Dhamma?...' one with disrespect and not even faith into geneosity, not to speak about Sila able to receive higher, even the goid Dhamma? "By words and ways"

Comment: Sure, it's not easy to answer when used to give Dhamma between advertising and for others profit: any answer would be therefore corrupt, approving wrong oneself, right?

Comment: @user21819 Ven. Ajahn Brahm has published books and has regular talks on YouTube. I'm sure he doesn't take money from it. It all goes to the Buddhism Society of Western Australia, for which, he is the spiritual head. According to [this page](https://bswa.org/teachers/ajahn-brahm/ajahn-brahm-bio/), "Ajahn Brahm has authored three popular books that are available commercially ... The royalties raised from sales of these books goes to the activities of the Buddhist Society of Western Australia."

Comment: As if he wouldn't be a remarkable sign of corruption. It's like citing Devatatta on discussing Dhamma... but good to bring up the most huge thieves.